# Handling Spring Cloud Config Server when its underlying remote git server is unreliable

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I noticed config server crashes whenever the underlying git server is either down or its performance is degraded (slow response).

The config server is deployed on a CloudFoundry-based platform which means the baseDir, which the config server is cloning the remote repository on, gets wiped out whenever the app restarts after crashing.

My intent is, even the remote git server becomes unavailable, I want my config server to still work by using its local repository.

My suspicion is that querying the health check endpoint of the config server may cause it to crash because whenever it gets hit the config server tries to check updates from remote git server which takes time when it's degraded or down. Eventually all these requests to health check pile up which may cause the config server to crash. Our load balancer queries this health check endpoint every 5 seconds.

Is there a way to handle this issue? Is there a better way to recover from crashes? The problem is when it crashes, which may really happen in case of fault on infrastructure level and coincides with git remote server being down or degraded, there's no way to recover as it will fail to clone the repo from the remote git server when it restarts.